# Detaching ERPNext or any frappe app from source git repository

Tags: git, github, frappe

At first, i am not refering to the original stackoverflow **frappe** tag. I am talking about this [frappe](https://frappe.io/).

Normally **frappe** or **ERPNext**(a frappe app) is installed via [frappe-bench](https://github.com/frappe/bench), and update the installed app via this command-

```
bench update
```

While updating, it fetches data from official frappe git repo.

Now what i want to do is detach ERPNext or any frappe app from source repository so that when i run **bench update**, it only take updates from the changes i have made in the source code, not from the github repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done the following steps to detach a frappe app (in my case **ERPNext**) from source repository-

At first, i have moved to **frappe-bench/apps/erpnext** via terminal and than set remote url for that app towards a private repo i have made, by

```
git remote set-url origin git://my-repo.url.here
```

And than i run the following command to check the remote version for erpnext-

```
git remote -v
```

It shows following output-

```
origin  https://github.com/my_git_user_name/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/my_git_user_name/REPOSITORY.git (push)
upstream  https://github.com/frappe/bench.git (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/frappe/bench.git (push)
```

That means, though i set my apps remote url towards my own repo, **bench update** command will still update the app from **upstream**, in my case, [frappe/bench](https://github.com/frappe/bench).

So i have first removed the upstream-

```
git remote rm upstream
```

And than set new upstream towards my repo-

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/my_git_user_name/REPOSITORY.git
```

Than i have gone to **bench-repo** folder via terminal and run the following command to migrate the changes-

```
bench migrate
```

Now if i run **bench update**, i see that my app is updating from my private repo. (Though, bench will update from official repo)

These steps can be done for any frappe app.